# Azure devops: How to distinguish between Microsoft and Self hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops

To know if you are on CI of working locally you can use [TF_BUILD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), but I could not see any environment variable that helps me discern between a *self-hosted* and a *microsoft-hosted* agent.

How can you do that, without having to manually define a custom environemnt variable in our *self-hosted* machines?

Update: why do I need this? There are things that work in one way or another depending if it is ms-hosted or self-hosted. e.g. python virtual environements see  [microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks Issue 15417](http://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15417).

Comment: Why you sound like it is bad to "manually define a custom environemnt variable"?

Comment: Sadly, many things in our test infrastructure are not automated and I would like to avoid adding this variable manually, at some point someone will forget it to add it to new machines and strange errors will happen. If in the end there is no other way, I gues I will have to do that. I was hoping something similar to TF_BUILD would exist already.

Comment: But Microsoft does not want to distinguish the two cases that much if you review the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pipeline-variables-devops-services The only obvious option is `Agent.Name` as "If you are using a self-hosted agent, then this name is specified by you. See agents."

Comment: They don't want but there are things that work in one way or another depending if it is ms-hosted or self-hosted. e.g. python virtual environements https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/15417. Agent.Name is good enough if you want to make it an answer go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [Agent.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services)? It is a predefined variable, which has:

> The name of the agent that is registered with the pool.
> If you are using a self-hosted agent, then this name is specified by you. See [agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents).

Assuming your naming scheme allows you to tell the difference between your own agents and MS hosted agents, that should do the job?

Comment: In the comments above Lex Li proposed that around 2 hours ago I would give the answer to him if he makes it an official answer, otherwise I will eventually accept yours :)

Comment: ah, true. I just jumped in with an answer before reading the comments, sorry

Comment: @Cesc you can accept this. I don't need too many points.